# error in metrop function from mcmc package: algorithm stops due to production of NAs during log-likelihood computation

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc

I am using the `metrop` function from the [**mcmc** package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mcmc) to estimate the posterior distribution of the coefficients of a linear regression (13 explanatory variables). 
The prior distributions of the coefficients are all gammas (shape and rates were chosen so that the distribution looks consistent). The posterior log-likelihood at the initial state is finite. Initial state is close to the means of the gamma distributions.

However, when launching the mcmc function, at least 9 times out of 10 I get the following error message:

> Error in system.time(out <- .Call("metrop", func1, initial, nbatch, blen,  :
>
> logh: func returned NA or NaN

In addition:

> Warning message:
>   In dnorm(y, mean = pred, sd = ecart_type, log = T) : NaNs produced

And when the algorithm works, the acceptance ratio is very weak (~0.001).

*Does anyone know what could be the problem? Could this be due to the fact that the support of the proposal function includes negative values, which is not consistent with the gamma priors?*